# Symfony 3 - generateUrl includes app root dir in url

Tags: symfony

I'm building a symfony 3 project that works perfectly on my homestead machine (ubuntu 14) and tried to put it into staging on another machine, a debian 8.

I tried to generate the "/login" route but generateUrl returns a path on disk instead of a URL

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('login', [], true);
```

Generates the following

```
http://example.com/var/www/mySf3App/web/app_dev.phplogin
```

Where it should have been something like

```
http://example.com/app_dev.php/login
```

Route is defined as follows

```
/**
* @Route("/index", name="index")
* @Route("/")
*/
```

I simply don't get it, anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact coming from a wrongful nginx configuration, all is well now

Answer (score 0):

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL instead of true

from documentation :
[link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-from-a-template)